# What exactly is a counter resolution

Tags: stm32

Im using STM32F411CE. It has 2 kinds of counters, one kind has 16 bit counter resolution while the other has 32 bit resolution. What exactly is the difference?
I assume its going to be better to take the one with larger resolution.

EDIT: So what exactly is going to be advantage of bigger resolution, am I going to be able to generate more precise PWMs?

Comment: Don't confuse range with resolution. It may be they are both clocked from the same set of sources so neither has more resolution.

Comment: On these parts they all have configurable prescalers, so the range can be expanded as needed by dividing the clock, at the resulting cost of resolution.

Comment: A counter resolution  may be likely if the first resolution fails

Answer (score 4):

This simply refers to the maximum count value. It depends what you are counting, but frequently it is possible to prescale the input to the counter (for example, increment it every 256 clock cycles rather than every clock). If you use a prescaler, you can still count large time intervals using a counter with fewer bits - but the precision will be reduced (the smallest interval will be the prescaled clock, rather than the original clock).

If you need a precise, non-power-of-two fraction, more count bits makes this easier. If less accuracy is needed, a 'cheaper' counter will be OK (and the manufacturer trades off the provided peripheral complexity for cost and power consumption).

Answer (score 2):

It's horses for courses, that is, it depends what you want to do.

A 16 bit counter will count 0 to 65535, a 32 bit counter will count to 0 to more than 4G, but will require more transfers to read.

Generally, use the smallest counter you can for any given task, to spare the larger ones for when you need the extra size.

Depending on how they are implemented, you may find that shorter counters are specified to be able to count faster than large ones (it's to do with how the carry is implemented internally).

Answer (score 2):

A 16-bit counter can count up to \$ 2^{16} \$ = 65,536 unsigned or -32768 to 32767 signed.

A 32-bit counter can count up to \$ 2^{32} \$ = 4,294,967,296 unsigned or -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 signed.

Use the 32-bit if you need to track numbers greater than \$ 2^{16} \$.

> EDIT: So what exactly is going to be advantage of bigger resolution, am I going to be able to generate more precise PWMs?

You are still confused about "resolution". The resolution of a counter is one bit regardless of how high the counter can go. The term is used in a different way for ADC or DAC conversions where the converter is able to "resolve" to one bit in \$ 2^8  = \frac {1}{256}\$ of full-scale, for example.

Your PWM resolution will be determined by the PWM output function on the relevant pins of that chip.

The counters are (likely to be - but I haven't read the datasheet) just general purpose counters. Sometimes 65,535 just isn't enough - e.g., if counting milliseconds it will wrap at 65.535 s so your code would only last a minute!

Comment: Yeah, but with this bigger counter I could avoid using prescaler for the standard servo-kind PWM generation, isnt that correct?

Comment: I don't know. Edit your question again and explain what problem you are trying to solve, what you've tried and where you're stuck. Quote the device PWM number of bits too since that seems to be related to your real question. And hyperlink the datasheet and quote page numbers, ...

Answer (score 1):

It is like a clock/stopwatch that only counts seconds up to a minute or a clock that counts minutes and seconds but not hours.   Sure you can use a kitchen timer as an alarm clock but you have to set it and wake up every hour or so, because it only has that resolution.  Or you can get a clock that can measure hours minutes and seconds.

Another way to look at this is a tape measure that has ticks down to a 16th of an inch, vs a tape measure that only has ticks every inch or one that only has ticks every foot.  Because the rule for that tape measure is that it can only support a resolution of N units of distance per tick.

A 16 bit timer rolls over after 65536 timer ticks.  A 32 bit every 4 billion and some.  More ticks on the measuring tape vs less.  What you cant do with your kitchen timer is change the unit of time, you cant make a kitchen timer that does minutes and seconds and change the units of time to hours and minutes, you dont have a choice for a prescaler.  Many of these devices you can change a prescaler, you can perhaps change it from divide by 1 to divide by 4.  So that 16 bit timer can now measure 65536 times 4 units of time but can only represent that in units of four clocks, kind of like a tape measure with inches but no 16ths.  If you only had a 20 bit timer you could have the resolution and the distance.

Say the clock feeding the peripherals is 1Mhz, which is 1 microsecond resolution.  Every 1 microsecond the timer ticks.  With a 16 bit timer with a divide by 1 prescaler you can measure in units of 1 microsecond, up to 65536 microseconds but that timer rolls over every 0.065536 seconds, so if you want that resolution but over a longer duration you need more bits, you can deal with it with interrupts and incrementing some other set of bits, a register a memory location, but that is effectively just adding more bits.   If you have a 20 bit timer at 1Mhz and a prescaler of divide by 1 then you can still have the accuracy of 1us but roll over now at 1.0486... seconds. So you can measure things up to a second at 1us accuracy or resolution.  A 32 bit timer 4295-ish seconds before it rolls over so 1us resolution for over an hour.  With this example 16 bit timer, if you instead use a divide by 4 prescaler, you can now measure up to 0.2621... seconds but at a resolution of 4us.

So from your example of a PWM, you can support longer pwm periods with the same resolution with more bits. using the 1Mhz example above you could not have a 1 second pwm period with a 1us resolution using the 16 bit timer you could either have a 1 second pwm period with a 16us resolution using the 16 bit timer or you could have your cake and eat it too, a 1 second pwm period with a 1us resolution.

More ticks in the ruler means you can have a longer tape measure AND measure with a 16th of an inch resolution (or mm resolution but more meters of overall tape).  Less ticks overall means either less accuracy or shorter overall length.

This is an stm32, there is no penalty for reading a 32 bit timer vs a 16 bit, if anything the 16 bit measurement costs more as the arm registers are 32 bit and the code generated will have to sign extend or mask.